# Is there a way to print out the observations of a single level?

Tags: r, dataframe, with-statement, levels

Within a data frame, I have a variable (var1) that has 3 levels (X, Y, Z) and I would like to print out all the observations on level Z. How could I do this? I've tried using a with() function, but haven't had any luck

```
table(var1)
var1
X   Y  Z
18  36  1
```

Comment: perhaps `table(var1, exclude= c('X', 'Y'))`, though it would help to have your dput(var1) to play with.

Answer (score 1):

Is your variable a column in your data frame?

If it is you could just filter with dplyr

```
df %>%
filter(var1== "z")
```